# How to dump process in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, memory, process

I want to dump memory of windows process using just command line and without 3rd party tools. Is that possible if we assume that all necessary privileges aquired.

Maybe it is possible to do using powershell? I have found it possible using `procdump` utility but this one is from sysinternals imho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Out-Minidump](https://github.com/mattifestation/PowerSploit/blob/master/Exfiltration/Out-Minidump.ps1) function for PowerShell:

> Out-Minidump writes a process dump file with all process memory to
>   disk. This is similar to running procdump.exe with the '-ma' switch.

Basic usage:

- Enable PowerShell script execution via [Set-ExecutionPolicy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849812.aspx) cmdlet. It should be `Bypass`, `Unrestricted` or `RemoteSigned`. [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647429/powershell-on-windows-7-set-executionpolicy-for-regular-users):

  > If you (or a helpful admin) runs Set-ExecutionPolicy as administrator,
  >   the policy will be set for all users. (I would suggest "remoteSigned"
  >   rather than "unrestricted" as a safety measure.)
  >
  > NB.: On a 64-bit OS you need to run Set-ExecutionPolicy for 32-bit and
  >   64-bit PowerShell separately.
- Download `Out-Minidump.ps1`
- Unblock it using File properties in Explorer ([alternate ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617509/unblock-a-file-with-powershell))

  [image: Unblock File]
- Launch PowerShell and [dot source](http://ss64.com/ps/source.html) function from the `Out-Minidump.ps1` (note first dot):

```powershell
. c:\path\to\Out-Minidump.ps1
```

- Now you can actually create dump of the process using this syntax:

```powershell
Get-Process 'notepad.exe' | Out-Minidump -DumpFilePath C:\temp
```

- To get help, run this command:

```powershell
Get-Help Out-Minidump -Full
```

Comment: thanks, actualy this is using 3rd party, however it is open source so I can be sure that this code does won't do anything wrong

Comment: Well, it depends on how you define `3rd party`. Basically, this code just executes [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx) function and the PowerShell itself is native to the Windows 2008. But I can see your point.